# Using bootstrap3 with bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a project using only bs3, but I have created a project apart with bs4 that need to be included and I wanted a solution for using both in my code(I know that it should be used only one version but this is not possible right now) and I want something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <bs3>
  <nav></nav>
 </bs3>

</bs4>
 here will be the content page created in bs4
</bs4>

 <bs3>
  <footer></footer>
 </bs3>
</body>
</html>
```

This would be a great solution to the actual project but can accept other solutions.

Comment: Porting your application to bootstrap 4 is the only decent way. Everything else is a dirty and very bad idea.

Comment: ya, you can not do that. Most classes were renamed or changed and there are things bootstrap 4 can do that bootstrap 3 can't do. the best option is to spend some time upgrading from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap4. Or find the classes that you added using bootstrap 4 and find their equivalent in bootstrap 3 and use them. But I wouldn't recommend doing that. and as @maio290 said the best way is to move toward bootstrap 4.